# GitKraken Not Recognizing LFS - The Pathways appear consistent but I do not see it

Tags: git-lfs, gitkraken

I've some experience with Git Kraken, but am working on a video game mod that uses LFS.  The paths seem correct - it is C\Program Files\Git LFS.  Nevertheless, GiKraken is not recognizing the LFS in preferences so I feel at a loss.

I understand that Git LFS should show up in preferences (https://help.gitkraken.com/gitkraken-client/git-lfs/) but I do nto see it.